# Trying to remove data from Data Frame with two Conditions

Tags: r

I am trying to remove data from a data frame based off of conditions from two columns.

```
Data1 <- Data[- grep("",Data$Item# || "12345" Data$Charge)
```

Basically I would like to remove the entire row if there is no value in `Data$Item#` and if there is the value "12345" in `Data$Charge`. I can do them each separately but cannot combine them.

Here's the data

```
Item#   Charge 
50      00000
61      12345
        12345
43      00000
        02521
7       12345
```

What I am trying to get to is

```
50      00000
61      12345
43      00000 
        02521
7       12345
```

Comment: In your code you use 'or' but in your question you used 'and', so I'm not sure what the condition is, but something like this should work: `Data1 <- Data[ -c(which(Data$Item# %in% "" | Data$Charge %in% "12345" ))`

Comment: If you need more assistance it would be really helpful if you added a If you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)  with an example how the corresponding **result** should look like, in an edit to your question. That way it's easier for others to finda and test their answers.

Comment: Your data and your result are identical and neither has two columns. Probably something like `Data1 <- Data[ -(Data$Item=="" | Data$Charge=="12345"), ]`. Note the comma after the logical expression and the closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code. Firstly, you have a "#" in one of your column names, which means you need to quote the column name; otherwise R will think you are starting a comment and will ignore the rest of the line. So your line

```
Data1 <- Data[- grep("",Data$Item# || "12345" Data$Charge)
```

will be interpreted as

```
Data1 <- Data[- grep("",Data$Item
```

by R, which will give you a syntax error.

In any case, this syntax isn't how `grep` works. If you want to test columns based on multiple regexes, you can use multiple `grepl` functions, each of which returns a logical vector, and just combine these. However, you can't use `grep` or `grepl` with an empty string, since **every** string contains an empty string! You can test for an empty string just by using `== ""`

When subsetting by rows, you need a comma after the conditions and the closing bracket, as @dcarlson pointed out.

Lastly, you should use `&` if you want to find the cases where only both conditions apply rather than `||`.

Therefore your code should be:

```r
Data1 <- Data[-which(Data$'Item#' == "" & grepl("12345", Data$Charge)),]
Data1
#>   Item# Charge
#> 1    50      0
#> 2    61  12345
#> 4    43      0
#> 5         2521
#> 6     7  12345
```

I believe this matches your expected output.

---

### Data used

```
df <- structure(list(`Item#` = c("50", "61", "", "43", "", "7"), Charge = c("0", 
"12345", "12345", "0", "2521", "12345")), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = "data.frame")
```